# Purchase music on iPhone ... download on phone and computer?

Tags: iphone, itunes

If I purchase a song on my iPhone, will I be allowed to download it on my iMac for free?

Usually I purchase music on my Imac and transfer it to my phone, but I am away from my desktop and would like to download an album on my phone, then download the same content on my desktop later. Does iTunes work like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**,

The next time you sync your phone (if you have sync music turned on), it will transfer any new purchases to your computer. It checks for this every time you sync.

It is the same idea with the applications. When you purchase an application through the iphone, it will also sync to the computer on your next sync (if you have application syncing checked).

I personaly do this all the time and it has worked great every single time.

Comment: When two people answer equally useful, trogdor wins =)

Comment: Thanks :(... lol, anyway... Trogdor?

Comment: @Wil: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30462/troggy-needs-an-image

Comment: Also: This explains where that came from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homestar_Runner

Comment: haha ... I didnt know there was history with troggy getting his picture :) I thought the name was because of the picture, not the other way around >.<

Answer (score 1):

If you purchased it through Itunes on your phone, it should appear in Itunes on your Mac next time you sync everything and you will be able to transfer/play again exactly the same as if you had purchased it on your Mac in the first place.